# How do I get the count of each group in MS Reports?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report

In MS Reports, I have a tablix(table) where I group on `foo`.

How do I get the count for each group?

This is how I would do it for the total count: `=Count(Fields!foo.Value)` , but it's not enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh I just do a normal count, on each row/group. And since it's inside a group it's per default give me the count of the group.

Comment: Does the foo.Value contain NULL value? What do you mean it is not enough? Is the exact number of the rows not equal to the `Count(Fields!foo.Value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have to add anything to `=Count(Fields!foo.Value)` . When it's inside a group it return the count of the group.